# Varnish logrotate not resuming logging

Tags: varnish

I have varnish-3.0.6 running on Scientific Linux 6.6, and I am seeing a problem with the logrotated script that comes with the varnish package. It seems like the postrotate script:
/bin/kill -HUP `cat /var/run/varnishlog.pid 2>/dev/null` 2> /dev/null || true
does not properly reload the program, and it does not log to the file post rotate. Reloading the service does fix the problem. Any body else seen this problem?